# Why should I prefer OneNote App vs MS Office OneNote?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, windows-8-apps

I'm working on my Win10 laptop and I can chose between OneNote App and Desktop App (MS Office).

In what scenario should I prefer one or the other? Why is Microsoft leaving this choice on a laptop machine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's your choice. You have to decide by your own if you prefer the touch or the desktop version of Onenote. I would recommend to use the touch version for tablets etc. and for desktop computer and Laptops the desktop version.

Windows ask you that by default. It doesn't matter on what device you are using. An other example is the Internet Explorer. There are also a touch and a desktop version, where you can choose which one you prefer to use.

Also [here](https://www.thurrott.com/uncategorized/5358/windows-10-tip-choose-the-right-onenote-app) is an interesting article about that.